# proper way to destroy knockout ViewModel

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a fulltext search app.  With each new search the user initiates, contextual passages and related descriptive data, returned from the server, are mapped to a viewmodel using the mapping plugin.

**But before the new view model can be instantiated, the viewmodel instantiated from previous search needs to be destroyed, and all DOM elements created from it, removed from the DOM.**

What is the proper way to do destroy (or remove items from) that stale ViewModel, created with the mapping plugin?

EDIT:
I don't understand, from the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), how to use any of these methods:

```
          mappedRemoveAll
          mappedDestroy
          mappedDestroyAll
```

or how to combine multiple calls to the `fromJS` method with the `key mapping`, so that I could use `mappedRemove` method. I'm getting an error that my object does not support `mappedRemove`.

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html

Comment: More details or some code will help...

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Is there a way to "blow away" the entire view model that was created by the mapping plugin `fromJS` in one fell swoop, like MyViewModel.empty() ?

Comment: Why empty it? You can remove the element it is bound to (that is, reverse the applyBindings as described in the link above) and then just let GC take care of it

Comment: It is a complex nested object bound to *many* DOM elements using nested foreach binding. Isn't the whole point in using a View Model to not deal with the UI directly, but to deal with the model?   I'm looking for a way to tell knockout, "This model is defunct. Please remove all DOM elements knockout has created from it."

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a high level `searchResult` object that holds references to all the other complicated objects you mention.  In that case, let's say your top level viewModel looks like this:

```
var vm = {
    something: ko.observable(),
    somethingElse: ko.observable(),
    searchResult: ko.observable()
};
```

and that you process all the mapping and assign the resulting large object to `searchResult`.  Well, then all you'd need to do is assign a different value to searchResult.  Knockout will, as efficiently as possible, handle all the DOM element disposal.  And your old object won't be referenced by anything anymore so the Garbage Collector would clean it up.  If other parts of your page are holding onto references inside `vm.searchResult`, then you could implement a dispose function and clean those up.

Comment: My searchResults object  is fed to the plugin's `mapping.fromJS` method. My searchResults object, before it is mapped is a set of title objects; each title object contains the contextual passage(s) where the search term appears; and each word in a passage is itself an object with attributes. I've edited my question to explain which plugin methods I'm having trouble with.